# angular 2 - 6 date form field prevent clear

Tags: angular, forms, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a pre-filled date input :

[image]

It's pre-filled and in all potential use-cases has cause to be changed but never cause to be emptied.

I would like to prevent it being emptied.

here's my html code :

```
<form class="details" [formGroup]="forcastForm" [style.fontSize.px]="13">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class=".col-lg-8 .col-xl-12">
      <mat-form-field class="my-date-input">
        <mat-label i18n="confirmed date">Date</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="date" formControlName="dateFC">
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

and my typescript :

```
forcastForm: FormGroup;

constructor(
  private fb: FormBuilder,
  private datePipe: DatePipe)
  {
    const j = new Date;
    let month = (j.getUTCMonth() + 1).toString();
    if(month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    const dateCode = j.getUTCFullYear().toString() + month + j.getUTCDate().toString();
    const dt = this.datePipe.transform(j, 'yyyy-MM-dd');

    this.forcastForm = fb.group({
      savedId: new FormControl({value: dateCode, disabled: false}, Validators.required),
      dateFC: new FormControl({value: dt, disabled: false}, Validators.required),
      comentary: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: false}, Validators.required),
    });

  }
```

I'm okay with hiding the **x** icon via `/deep/` css but there is no real way to see the **x**'s code in the code inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `required` attribute to the input element:

```
<input matInput type="date" required formControlName="dateFC">
```